# The integral of log of a quadratic

Tags: integration

I want to calculate a definite integral of the form
$$
\int_0^1 \log(a x^2 + b x + c)dx
$$
where $a,b,c$ are parameters, and can be assumed to be nonnegative integers.

I am guessing that this kind of integral must be well known, but my integral-fu is sadly lacking. Could someone point me towards a solution or a reference?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: @Yos : No! With this change of variable, you won't have $dt = dx$...

Answer (score 4):

If $u$ and $v$ are the roots of the polynomial,

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-u)(x-v)$$
Then
$$\int_0^1\log (ax^2+bx+c)dx=\log a+\left(\int_0^1\log(x-u)dx+\int_0^1\log(x-v)dx\right)$$

The formula works even if $u$ anb $v$ are complex (and not real). But in this case you may prefer to complete the square:

$$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x-\frac b{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
and then use a suitable change to get something of the form $k(t+1)^2$.

It fails when $u$ or $v$ are in the interval of integration, but, since $a,b,c\ge 0$, this can not happen.

Comment: Thank you, elegant and simple!