# Can someone solve this integral or what is wrong with it?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quantum-field-theory

I am trying to perform an integral but the main cause of issues and errors is the following part
\begin{equation}
-\int_0^1dx\: \log(m^2+Q^2x(x-1))
\end{equation}
where there are some other $x$'s multiplied to the front of it but I can get rid of those by integration by parts (if you want to know *one* of the polynomials multiplied to it is $(20x^2 - 40x + 21)(m^2 + Q^2(x-1)x)$ but I do not know if that would help trying to solve this thing. For reference this integral arose after doing a loop-integral in QFT and I am finally at the end stages of the calculation and this monster appears; this is after performing the momentum integral by $\epsilon$-expansion, keeping terms up to order $\epsilon^1$, and now I am doing the $dx$ integral that came from the Feynman parameter trick of splitting up the denominator of $1/AB = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{Ax + B(1-x)}$.

I don't have a nice integral book on stand by so I am turning to here. *Mathematica* takes about 10 minutes to do just the $\log$ integral and it spits out
\begin{equation}
-\frac{2 \sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2}}\right)}{Q}-\log \left(m^2\right)+2
\end{equation}
with the following if condition
\begin{equation}
\Im(m)^2\leq \Re(m)^2\land \left(\frac{\sqrt{Q^4-4 m^2 Q^2}}{Q^2}\notin \mathbb{R}\lor \Re\left(\frac{\sqrt{Q^4-4 m^2 Q^2}}{Q^2}\right)<-1\lor \Re\left(\frac{\sqrt{Q^4-4 m^2 Q^2}}{Q^2}\right)>1\right)\land \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{4 \Im(m) \Re(m)}{\Im(Q) \Re(Q)}}\notin \mathbb{R}\lor \Re\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{4 \Im(m) \Re(m)}{\Im(Q) \Re(Q)}}\right)\geq 1\lor \Im(m) \left(\frac{\Re(m) \Re(Q)}{\Im(Q)}+\Im(m)\right)\leq \Re(m) \left(\frac{\Im(m) \Im(Q)}{\Re(Q)}+\Re(m)\right)\right)\land \left(\Re\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2}}{Q}\right)\neq 0\lor \Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2}}{Q}\right)<-1\lor \Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2}}{Q}\right)>1\right)
\end{equation}

If I said I knew what that meant I'd be lying.

Any suggestions about how to massage this integral or where to look are very helpful, thanks!

Comment: This [general formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223603/) may be useful

Comment: Do you know the sign of $4 m^2 - Q^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Mathematica does not know anything about $m$ and $Q$.

If you just type

`Integrate[Log[m^2+Q^2*x(x-1)],{x,0,1}, Assumptions -> m>0 && Q>0]`

Mathematica returns immediately
$$2(\log(m)-1)+\frac{2 \sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2} }{Q}\,\,\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{4 m^2-Q^2}}\right)\qquad \text{if}\qquad 2m>Q$$

Now, if you write
$$\log \left(m^2+Q^2 x(x-1) \right)=\log(Q^2)+\log(x-a)+\log(x-b)$$

where
$$(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{Q^2-4 m^2}}{2 Q}$$ you will get, without any condition
$$(1-a) \log (1-a)+a \log (-a)+(1-b) \log (1-b)+b \log (-b)-2$$ which covers all cases.

Comment: You have one to many factors of $x$ in your $\log$ function. The original integral had $m^2 + Q^2x(x-1)$ not $m^2 + Q^2x(x-1)x$ so was this just a typo or?

Comment: @MathZilla. Sorry for the typo !